# Distribute m=17 cards to n=7 entities

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, equivalence-relations, stirling-numbers

Every entity must receive at least 2 cards and all cards have to be distributed. Only the cards and not the entities are distinguishable. My approach was as follows:

Since every entity has to receive at least 2 cards, I first pick $n$ cards, i.e. $m\choose n$. The remaining $m-n$ cards can then be distributed across the $n$ entities using Stirling numbers of the second kind, guaranteeing that each entity receives its remaining card and that all remaining cards are distributed without distinguishing the entities. The final construct is then:

$${m\choose n}\cdot S(m-n, n)$$

The actual solution, however, is:
$$\frac{17!}{6!1!(2!)^6(5!)^1}+\frac{17!}{5!1!1!(2!)^5(3!)^1(4!)^1}+\frac{17!}{4!3!(2!)^4(3!)^3}$$
which uses the fact that the number of equivalence relations over $[N]$ which contain exactly $\lambda_i$ many $i$-element equivalence classes is given by:
$$\frac{N!}{\lambda_1!\lambda_2!..\lambda_N!(1!)^{\lambda_1}(2!)^{\lambda_2}..(N!)^{\lambda_N}}$$
and that given the requirements of the task, the 17 cards can be distributed across the 7 entities in three ways:
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5) (i.e. six $2$-element classes and one $5$-element class),
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4), or
(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3).

This gives a much larger number than my solution. In what way do the two differ and what is my formulation actually describing?

Comment: I don't follow how your solution fits in with the actual problem statement.  "*Since every enttity has to receive at least $2$ cards, I first pick $n$ cards*"  Is $n$ here the same $n$ in the title?  What do you do with those cards once you've picked them?  Gave one to each "entity" without caring which was which?  Okay... now when you go to use stirling numbers... are the entities really still indistinguishable?  Remember that now the entities have a distinguishing feature... namely which card they received in the first step.

Comment: But then, if you were to continue with this line of thought, then you run into the issue of having to keep track of which order cards were given to the entity, be it in the first step when you first distributed the initial $n$ cards, or in the later step when you distribute the remaining $m-n$ cards.  Correctly taking care of the overcounting here with this approach seems difficult at best... the approach taken by the book on the other hand is clean and straightforward (*but still relies a bit heavily on casework looking at all the different ways you could split 17 as described*)

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting to see the distinction more clearly now.